# Why is this strstr() returning false?

Tags: php, strstr

I am trying to find whether a string contains a certain text or not using strstr()

```
$t = "http://site.com/image/d2737cda28cb420c972f7a0ce856cf22";
var_dump(strstr('/image/', $t));
exit;
```

But this gives `false`. Why is it giving fasle? How to fix it?

Comment: you should use strpos , faster, less resources

Comment: Clear evidence that a Jedi wrote php. "In a haystack, a needle you must find."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parameters are inverted (see [`strstr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)). This is the correct way of using it:

```
strstr($t, '/image/');
```

Comment: Oh... why does php always mix up with `needle` and `haystack`?

Answer (score 2):

you should use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) , faster, less resources, from the manual with your vars

```
<?php
$t = "http://site.com/image/d2737cda28cb420c972f7a0ce856cf22";
$findme   = '/image/';
$pos = strpos($t, $findme);

// Note our use of ===.  Simply == would not work as expected
// because the position of 'a' was the 0th (first) character.
if ($pos === false) {
    echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the string '$mystring'";
} else {
    echo "The string '$findme' was found in the string '$mystring'";
    echo " and exists at position $pos";
}
?>
```

Comment: How about just `if(!$pos)`? Will that omit the need of `===`?

Comment: I accepted other answer as that is the answer to my question. But I am using your solution. +1

Comment: nooo the points! all those lovely points i have lost :-; -kidding all good ;-)

Answer (score 0):

try like this instead

```
<?php
$t = "http://site.com/image/d2737cda28cb420c972f7a0ce856cf22";
var_dump(strstr($t, '/image/'));
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see the documentation of the function.

Validates the syntax.

[php/documentation/function.strstr.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)

The correct use would: var_dump(strstr($t, '/image/'));